# no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int> >’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c++, vector, std, smart-pointers

I have an `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>` and I am trying to access an element using the `[]` operator. How can I access a specific index of the vector contained within the `std::unique_ptr`?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> x;
    x[0] = 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the purpose of storing a dynamically allocated `std::vector`? Do you have this requirement?

Comment: You have a pointer to a vector, but it *doesn't point anywhere*.

Comment: As for your problem, would you still wonder if it was a simple non-smart pointer? Like `std::vector<int>* x;`? A smart pointer still behaves like a pointer.

Comment: There's a custom deleter on the unique_ptr so that it will blank the memory to 0xFF once it goes out of scope. I didn't include that cause I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: What is the reason for that "blanking"? What problem is that supposed to solve? It makes no sense except for debugging purposes, and there are plenty of memory-debuggers that can help you with that (and Visual Studio for debug builds will mark free'd heap-memory itself, possibly overriding your "blanking").

Comment: We are programming onto an embedded processor which doesn't do any automatic blanking. We blank data such as symmetric keys which are used for decryption and the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a pointer to a vector, so you'd have to dereference it

```
(*x)[0] = 1;
```

or

```
x->at(0) = 1;
```

I am curious, however, why you need to dynamically allocate a `std::vector`? That container will already dynamically allocate the underlying array, so I would just have `x` be a `std::vector<int>` directly.

If you *do* keep a pointer to a vector, at least make sure you allocate the object before using it

```
auto x = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>();
```

Comment: Thanks! Deferencing with * did the trick. I was mistakenly using .get() instead of *.